# Jython 2.7 beta 2 install .jar interpreter error in Eclipse

Tags: java, python, eclipse, python-2.7, jython

I'm new to using Jython on eclipse and I want to download the latest version of Jython which is Jython 2.7-Beta2

When I try to add the .jar file of Jython 2.7 beta 2 to Eclipse preference > Jython Interpreter I receive this error message: `python stdlib not found or stdlib without .p file`

When I proceed anyway it takes very long time to add it to PYTHONPATH (Synch PYTHONPATH (100%)), and then when I create a new PyDev project using Jython interpreter I get errors for importing nltk and pprint!

Also, I don't know how to add a java file to the project with keeping the pydev perspective.

Any help?
Thanks in advance